# How to multiple call when navigate to other screen in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation, jetpack-compose-navigation

In my application, I added animations anytime we navigate to another screen:

```
  NavHost(
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = startDestination,
    enterTransition = {
      slideIntoContainer(
        towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Companion.Left,
        animationSpec = tween(TRANSITION_ANIMATION_DURATION)
      )
    },
    exitTransition = {
      slideOutOfContainer(
        towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Companion.Left,
        animationSpec = tween(TRANSITION_ANIMATION_DURATION)
      )
    },
    popEnterTransition = {
      slideIntoContainer(
        towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Companion.Right,
        animationSpec = tween(TRANSITION_ANIMATION_DURATION)
      )
    },
    popExitTransition = {
      slideOutOfContainer(
        towards = AnimatedContentTransitionScope.SlideDirection.Companion.Right,
        animationSpec = tween(TRANSITION_ANIMATION_DURATION)
      )
    }
  ) {

    composable(route = AppDestination.Recent.destination) { nav ->
      AbcRoute(navController = navController, entry = nav)
    }
}
```

And in the route:

```
@Composable
fun AbcRoute(
  navController: NavController,
  entry: NavBackStackEntry,
) {

  val objectA = entry.arguments?.getString(AppDestination.Abc.objectA)?.let {
    Json.decodeFromString<A>(it)
  } ?: return
 
  val viewModel = hiltViewModel<AbcViewModel>()

  val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle

  val state = viewModel.enhanceState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
  LaunchedEffect(lifecycle) {
    viewModel.initialize(objectA)
  }
```

In ViewModel, I start to call API every time the user opens the screen.
But the problem is, because it have animation so the screen recompose many time -> recall API many times.

- I added the request to ViewModel scope and it cancels but sometimes the call still succeeds, and it does not look like a good idea. Do we have the right approach for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using `lifecycle` as your key to the `LaunchedEffect`. Most of the time if I want to only execute a piece of code once in compose I use `LaunchedEffect(Unit){}`